# printing the first item in google custom search api in python

Tags: python, google-custom-search

I'm trying to conduct google custom search in python through api. by default it gives us 10 search results with items in it . what i want is to extract the item 'link' from all 10 results separately instead of all 10 together so that i can store each link of them in different variables.

Comment: Pl share the sample response from api.

Answer (score 0):

If the API response is stored in a variable resp1, you can write:

```
[i["link"] for i in resp1]
```

Well, this is the pythonic way, and will give you list of all "links" values in a single list.

However, if you want to do this one at a time, you can do

```
variable1 = resp1[0]["link"]
```

and keep changing the index 0 to 1 to 2 to 3...

Another non-pythonic way would be:

```
for i in resp1:
   print(i["link"])
```

You can print or store to a variable as needed.

Comment: tried one by one method 
but im getting an error like key error=0-----

from googleapiclient.discovery import build------
 


my_api_key = ""
my_cse_id = ""
query= "python"-------
def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service= build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
    return res--------

results= google_search(query, my_api_key, my_cse_id)---------
variable1=results[0]["link"]
print(variable1)